# Hibernate tries to insert data to a table that does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc

I have a database about movies and actors. I want to do is :
I want to fetch actor data (like name, surname, country, date of birth) from the corresponding arrayLists and insert that data into my actor table. And i want to do the same thing to my movie table. Here is a part of my code :

Then i am getting these errors :

- Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

  -Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

  -Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

  -Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'movies and tv series.actor_country' doesn't exist

The thing that i don't understand is why hibernate tries to insert data to a table that does not exist. I don't want a actor_country table. Can somebody help me please ?

I have created a no-argument constructor and initialize the arrayLists with some data.

Comment: We would need to see the definition of your entities. Are you using the `@Table` annotation to name your tables? If not, Hibernate will use your class names to figure it out.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, with your current design, you're stuck with an `actor_country` table. Defining a property as `@ElementCollection` of type `List` is going to create a child table. **How else would you store multiple countries in a relational database?**  You can control the name of the table by using the `@CollectionTable` in conjunction with the `@ElementCollection`.

If you don't want to store multiple countries, you can switch it to `@Basic` with a type of `String`.

Comment: So there is no way storing multiple countries without a child class ?

Comment: The child class isn't the problem. It's that you need a table to store them in. If you want to store multiple items in a database, you store each item as a record. How else would you do it in an RDBMS? If you go NoSQL, then it's a whole different thing.

Comment: Thank you very much